# How to display mobile view for mobile devices in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I have main and mobile sites: site.com and m.site.com.

How to display different views/themes in Yii2 for mobile and desktop devices?

May be I should using themes, but how display different views?
P.S. I don't want use responsive design. Thank you!

Comment: Extend `yii\web\Controller`, rewrite constructor or init function. Determine mobile/simple device, set `viewPath` and `layout` for your needs. Extend your further controllers form this one (where mobile views needed).

Comment: It's good idea, Ineersa. I will try it. Thank you!

Comment: But how to set view path, it's avalible only in 2.0.7. And how to change layout path?

Comment: `$this->viewpath = Yii::getAlias('@frontend/views/'.$this->id);` or redefine `getViewPath()`